# What is the easiest way to style/design the search box in SP2010?

Tags: search, branding

I think we have three options, correct me if wrong:

1. Implement a feature
2. Override the search classes in my style.css (`.s4-search table`, `.s4-search input`, `.s4-search .ms-searchimage`)
3. Implement a new custom search box control.

What's the easiest among these and appoint me to others if there's any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make it a feature, whatever way you choose. Then you could inject a delegate control with a  tag unless you prefer creating a master page with a custom CSS.

Comment: I have a custom master page... so what you suggest?

Comment: add a custom CSS file (avoid inline style elements) and then override the search box CSS classes.

Comment: after a huge research I found out that the best way is implementing a feature.. it can be done manually without visual studio, 
I followed steps of method 1 in this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pavankumar/archive/2009/03/24/customizing-small-search-box.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check this link out - I just wrote up how I normally go about styling the search box in sp2010 (MOSS) [Restyle a Sharepoint 2010 Search Box - Labs.steveottenad.com](http://labs.steveottenad.com/reskin-restyle-a-sharepoint-2010-search-box/) - This works for an out of the box install without having to do any masterpage editing. Editing the CSS is miles easier than trying to implement a custom feature or altering the master page to include a new control. However, if you do want to go that route, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc806230.aspx (it says 2007, but i can verify it works on sp2010).

Answer (score 1):

Another writeup, this time using the advanced search control.
[Style the OOB SharePoint advanced search control](http://labs.steveottenad.com/reskin-restyle-a-sharepoint-2010-search-box/) - Hope this helps as well.